# Call 2 functions in single ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am calling two functions on ng-click. But it doesn't work. I am not sure why the Refresh1() is not called when I cross-checked through debugger.

```
HTML CODE
<div class="row" ng-controller="PublishManifestCtrl">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-header bordered-bottom bordered-themeprimary">
            <i class="widget-icon fa fa-tasks themeprimary"></i>
            <span class="widget-caption themeprimary">Manifest Status</span>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-body">
            <form class="form-bordered" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="padding-left: 8px;">Manifest was last published to agents on <b>{{manifeststatus.manifestLastPublishedDate}}</b>.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="padding-left: 8px;">Manifest was last updated by <b> {{manifeststatus.lastUpdatedByUser}} </b> on <b>{{manifeststatus.manifestLastedUpdatedDate}}</b>.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
                        **<button id="PublishButton" class="btn btn-default shiny " ng-disabled="manifeststatus.enablePublishButton" ng-click="Save(manifeststatus);Refresh1()">Publish</button>**
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div id="statusDivPublish" ng-show="showstatus">
                        <alert type="{{alert.type}}">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

JSFILE

```
$scope.Save = function (data) {
       debugger;
        $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');
        //$http.get({ url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getmanifeststatus' });

        $scope.manifeststatus = data;

        $scope.showstatus = true;
        $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
        $(".statusDivPublish").show();

    }

    $scope.Refresh1 = function () {
        //refresh
        $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
            reload: true,
            inherit: false,
            notify: true
        });
    }    
});
```

new code

```
 $scope.Save = function (data) {
       debugger;
        $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');
        //$http.get({ url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getmanifeststatus' });

        $scope.manifeststatus = data;

        $scope.showstatus = true;
        $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
        $(".statusDivPublish").show();

        $scope.Refresh1();

    }

    $scope.Refresh1 = function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
        debugger;
         return {
            restrict: 'AC',
            link: function (scope, el, attr) {
                el.on('click', function () {
                    $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
                        reload: true,
                        inherit: false,
                        notify: true
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    };
 });
```

The first one updates and displays a successfull message, while the second function refreshes the page.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$scope.Save = function (data) {
   debugger;
    $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');
    //$http.get({ url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getmanifeststatus' });

    $scope.manifeststatus = data;

    $scope.showstatus = true;
    $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
    $(".statusDivPublish").show();
    $scope.refresh();

}
```

call refresh inside the first function and remove it from the ng-click.

Update
You have a different type of problem i had it too. you try to refresh a state inside a method, it's really difficult i solve that problem with this snippet

```
 if($state.current.name == /*name of the current state*/) {
     $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
     $modalInstance.close();
  }
  else {
      $modalInstance.close();
      $state.go(/*name of the current state*/);
  }
```

it's not difficult but it didn't behave like you have understand it.

UPDATE
taking your code

```
$scope.Refresh1 = function () {
    //refresh
    $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
}
```

Comment: The message is displayed, but the date is not refreshed.

Comment: can you please just edit the code that i have posted now, and what is this /*name of the current state? i didnt get it.

Comment: ReferenceError: $state is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.Refresh1 (publishmanifest.js:44)
    at Scope.$scope.Save (publishmanifest.js:37)
    at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12345)
    at angular-touch.js:472
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14401)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14500)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular-touch.js:471)
    at HTMLButtonElement.n.event.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: it throws an arror of state is undefined

Comment: it seems you don't have the $state injected

Answer (score 0):

Don't execute two function in one `ng-click`, instead add the `Refresh1` call to the end of the `Save` call, like so.

**HTML**

```
<button id="PublishButton" 
        class="btn btn-default shiny " 
        ng-disabled="manifeststatus.enablePublishButton" 
        ng-click="Save(manifeststatus)">Publish</button>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.Save = function (data) {
   debugger;
    $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');
    //$http.get({ url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getmanifeststatus' });

    $scope.manifeststatus = data;

    $scope.showstatus = true;
    $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
    $(".statusDivPublish").show();
    $scope.refresh();

}
```

**Update**

If you are using `AngularJS V1.2.2` or higher, then using `ui-router`, the following should work to reload the data.

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});
```

The shortest way to accomplish this though would be with:

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); //second parameter is for $stateParams
```

Its also worth noting that none of these will actually reload the page. If you want to reload the state AND the page, there is no `ui-router`method for it. Do `window.location.reload(true)`

**Update 2**

If you are receiving:

> $state is not defined at Scope.$scope.Refresh1
>   (publishmanifest.js:44) at Scope.$scope.Save (publishmanifest.js:37)
>   at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12345) at angular-touch.js:472 at
>   Scope.$eval (angular.js:14401) at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14500) at
>   HTMLButtonElement. (angular-touch.js:471) at
>   HTMLButtonElement.n.event.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3) at
>   HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

You are not injecting the `$state` service in your `controller`. You must do this in order to use it.

```
//without annotation (inferred, not safe when minifying code)
function Controller($scope, $state) {...}

//inline annotation
module.controller('Controller', ['$scope','$state', function($scope, $state) {...}]);

//$inject property annotation
function Controller($scope, $state) {...}
Controller.$inject = ['$scope', '$state'];
```

Pick one of the methods above to setup your controller to use `$state`.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: when I tried using that snippet of refresh, it throws an $state is undefined exception

Comment: * @license AngularJS v1.3.13

Comment: @SonamG You must inject `$state` check my updated answer.

Comment: can I use the annotation in the JS file itself?

Answer (score 0):

What about calling refresh inside of save in `$http` handler ?

Like this:

```
$http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus')
    .then(function(){
        $scope.Refresh1();
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make a third function like:

```
function3(data) {
    save(data);
    refresh1();
}
```